# How to bind a SOAP web service response data to a SpinnerView in Android?

Tags: android, web-services, android-layout, soap, ksoap2

I need to display the names from SOAP web services, when I was singin my application next page spinner and some textviews. I'm getting response about text fields.

But I need to know how to get data into the spinner?

Comment: it mean you want fill spinner from server response right?

Answer (score 2):

Basically you what you need to.

- First you need to send a HTTP request to your server.And you better do via AsyncTask without interrupting your UI thread.
- Secondly you need to parse the response from your request according to your needs.The response from web service can be either XML or JSON or something else.
- And the last one you need to write your custom adapter to populate your spinner and then set it as your spinner adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Get it into an array from the webservice in an async task and then populate the spinner from that.